# Saveall not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Im using cake 2.0.6 and im trying to save multiple records that are products my data output from the form is below;

I cant get it to save the two records, the fields in my form are set like; with 0 being the first record it should save. It wont save the 2 records for some reason. Ive turned off all validation for the product model and have no beforesave method

Any ideas whats wrong?

```
<input name="data[Product][0][product_code]"/>
<input name="data[Product][0][colour]"/>
<input name="data[Product][0][lead_time_weeks]"/>
<input name="data[Product][0][description]"/>
<input name="data[Product][0][height]" />
<input name="data[Product][0][width]" />
<input name="data[Product][0][depth]" />
<input name="data[Product][0][price]" />
<input name="data[Product][0][discount]" />
<input name="data[Product][0][discounted_price]" />
<input name="data[Product][0][quantity]"/>


<input name="data[Product][1][product_code]"/>
<input name="data[Product][1][colour]"/>
<input name="data[Product][1][lead_time_weeks]"/>
<input name="data[Product][1][description]"/>
<input name="data[Product][1][height]" />
<input name="data[Product][1][width]" />
<input name="data[Product][1][depth]" />
<input name="data[Product][1][price]" />
<input name="data[Product][1][discount]" />
<input name="data[Product][1][discounted_price]" />
<input name="data[Product][1][quantity]"/>


Array
(
    [Product] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_code] => fgfgf
                    [colour] => 
                    [lead_time_weeks] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [height] => 11111
                    [width] => 22222
                    [depth] => 
                    [price] => 
                    [discount] => 50
                    [discounted_price] => 
                    [quantity] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_code] => fgfgf
                    [colour] => 
                    [lead_time_weeks] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [height] => 123
                    [width] => 123
                    [depth] => 
                    [price] => 
                    [discount] => 50
                    [discounted_price] => 
                    [quantity] => 
                )

        )

)
```

EDIT:
Solution for future reference;
Call the save method like this;

$this->Product->saveAll($this->request->data['Product']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you call `saveAll`? The common mistake is to call it like

```
$this->Product->saveAll($data);
```

When you should have done it like

```
$this->Product->saveAll($data['Product']);
```

It has to be numerically indexed without the Model key

As per the docs:
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

> Note that we are passing $data['Article'] instead of usual $data. When
>   saving multiple records of same model the records arrays should be
>   just numerically indexed without the model key.

Comment: im calling it like this;

$this->Product->saveAll($this->request->data);

ill try your solution.

Comment: thanks for that i thought i had tried every thing in the book but this worked:

$this->Product->saveAll($this->request->data['Product']